# Proper terminology for non-const variable

Tags: c, constants

Is there a specific word in C that is used to refer to a read-write variable? For example, if I have:

```
      int a = 2;
const int b = 3;
```

I would refer to `b` as a `const`. What would be the proper terminology to refer to `a`? (Non-const? Default? Writeable? etc.)

Comment: `"variable with automatic storage duration"`?? -- It's just a variable...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin right, but aren't the storage class modifiers 'static', 'automatic', 'register', and 'extern'? 'const' would be a type qualifier (I think in the group of 'const', 'volatile', and 'restrict').

Comment: I don't ever recall seeing a specific term for just a variable. It is the absence of one of the modifiers that we are trying to describe. That's why I say it's just a variable of type `int` which in this case has automatic storage duration (not static, thread or allocated)

Comment: I usually work in C++, which might have different terminology, but there they’re usually called “non-`const`”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is *const-qualified* and `a` is *unqualified* / *non-const-qualified*.

`const` in *C* does not mean that its value cannot change, it just means that **you** as a programmer say that you're not going to change it. The value of a `const volatile` object may well be different on each access, hence it, too, would be ... variable?

Comment: @Anti -- I see. So `const` would go in `.readonly` but `const volatile` would just go in `.data` if it's in global scope?

Comment: @David542 the standard does not specify what will happen for those. A `const volatile` object could exist for example in some embedded system, where the linker would place it at some memory-mapped I/O device location

Comment: @David542: No, if you don't use any `__attribute__` stuff to put it in a special section, and/or a linker script to set a specific address for that a `const volatile` object with static storage class, it would go along with other `const` objects in `.rodata` in a normal C implementation like GCC.  (Or `.rdata` on Windows.)  The effect of `volatile` would just be to force actually reloading it once for every reference to it in the C source.

Answer (score -2):

b refer to integer constant and we assume it cannot change during the program.
each segment has a write-protected area where all the constants are stored.

- If const int is a local variable, then it is stored in the
  write-protected area of the stack segment.
- If const int is defined globally, then it is stored in write-protected area the data segment.

when we defined int a = 2, it is the default variable assignment and uses the automatic storage class.

Comment: `const` objects *can* be placed in read-only storage, but in practice that only happens for static storage class. If you take the address of `const int b` and pass that to another function (so the compiler has to actually materialize it in memory), it will just be in normal stack memory in any mainstream C implementation. (e.g. GCC for x86-64 GNU/Linux). 
Also, read-only global / static objects go in their own section, `.rdata` or `.rodata`, which is either linked as part of the *text* (not data) segment (because that's where other read-only stuff is, i.e. code), or on its own read-only noexec